# Is it possible to share .appx without trusted certificate? If not than how can I share/distribute my app without publishing?

Tags: ionic-framework, windows-10-universal

I have created a build which works fine in my system by when I share it with my team they get certificate issue while installing app. `Either you need a new certificate installed for this app package, or you need a new app package with trusted certificates. Your system administrator or the app developer can help. A certificate chain processed, but terminated in a root certificate which isn't trusted (0x800B0109)`

What are the ways by which, I can share build with my team before publishing it.

**Note**:Certificates cannot be attached in most of email client.

Answer (score 2):

In order for others to deploy your .appx or .MSIX, the app must be signed, and the users must trust the certificate you used to sign it. 
While developing your app you can use a test certificate that your team agrees to trust.